# Count number of action and show last date of action

Tags: mysql, datetime, aggregate-functions

I am querying an audit database to try and find out how many actions each user has completed and when their last action was.

The query I am using is :

```
SELECT user_id, 
       count(id) as actions, 
       datetime
  from auditing
 WHERE datetime>='2014-03-01 00:00:00' 
 GROUP BY user_id 
 ORDER BY `auditing`.`datetime` DESC
```

This correctly shows me the total number of items but it does not show the correct last date - the date it does show me it quite random i.e. not at the top or bottom of the list but taken from somewhere in the middle. I checked this for a number of entries produced and they are all wrong and do not reflect the latest action.

How can I get it to show me the last (most recent) event in the above query?

Example:

```
user_id | actions | datetime
1 | 10 | 2014-07-04 16:10:14
2 | 55 | 2014-07-05 11:15:08
3 | 8 | 2014-07-04 22:19:43
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should only `SELECT` columns that are part of your `GROUP BY` clause *or* are a result of an [aggregate function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html). You can and probably should [configure your database server](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by)  so that it would complain about your query. It would say something like:

```
ERROR 1055 (42000): 'datetime' isn't in GROUP BY
```

The reason behind it is, that you don't tell the database server *which* `datetime` value you want (the earliest, the average, the latest?). So in order to get the last value, try this query:

```
SELECT    user_id, count(id) as actions, max(datetime)
FROM      auditing
WHERE     datetime>='2014-03-01 00:00:00'
GROUP BY  user_id
ORDER BY  user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this:

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(actions), MAX(datetime)
FROM auditing
WHERE datetime>='2014-03-01 00:00:00'
GROUP BY user_id
```